# Prime and Irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Integral Domain, **D**, every associate of an irreducible *[resp. prime]* element of **D** is irreducible *[resp. prime].*

- I am done with irreducible part.
- For prime, I am stuch with this idea. So if **p** is prime, let say **x** is an associate of p then **p=xd** for some **d** in **D**. Since **p** is prime, then **p|x** or **p|d**. We need to show that **d** is prime. How?

Comment: Remember that if two ring elements $a,b \in R$ are associates, then $a = u b$ for some unit $u \in R$. So, use the definition of associate elements which makes your element $x$ necessarily a unit. Now how will the prime $p$ divide a unit? Then how must $p$ divide $d$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: By definition of associate, your $d$ must be a unit. So, you do not want to show that $d$ is prime. What you want to show is that if $x|ab$ then $x|a$ or $x|b$, and $x$ is not a unit.

An alternative way would be to observe that an element $p$ is prime if and only if $(p)$ is a prime ideal. Hence, show that $(x)$ is a prime ideal (this should follow very easily from the fact that $x$ is an associate of $p$).

Comment: So *p* is prime if and only if *(p)* is a prime ideal. And *p* and *x* are associates if and only if *(p)=(x)* So *(x)* is a prime ideal (????) that implies x is also prime. Does it make sense?

Comment: Depending on how you define a prime element, this should be straightforward using the definition of prime ideal.

Comment: I used a theorem that says *p* and *x* are associates if and only if *(p)=(x)*. Does it follow that *(x)* is a prime ideal since *(p)* is prime ideal? Then does it imply that *x* is prime?

Comment: Dear @ghet: If the two ideals are equal, then doesn't one of them having property $y$ imply the other also has property $y$, because they are equal?

Comment: Ok thanks so much.

Comment: Ok. So *p* and *x* are associates then *(p)=(x)*. Since p is nonzero then *(p)* is not {0} and *(x)* is not {0} so x is not zero. Since *p* is not unit *(p)* is not *D* and *(x)* is not *D* and *x* is not a unit. It remains to show that if *x|ab* then *x|a* or *x|b*. How? Any more tips??

Comment: You don't have to do the other approach if you know that if $(p)$ is a prime ideal then $(x)$ is a prime ideal, hence $x$ is prime.

Answer (score 1):

An element of your ring is prime if and only if it generates a prime ideal.  Now you know that (p) is a prime ideal. What do you know is true about the ideal (d)?

Comment: ideal (d) or ideal (x). Since p and x are associates then (p)=(x).

Comment: Right, I meant (x). So (x)  = (p), which is a prime ideal. Thus x generates a prime ideal, and x is prime.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\, $ unit $\rm\,u,\, $ prime $\rm\, p,\,$  $\rm\ up\mid xy\:\Rightarrow\:p\mid xy\:\Rightarrow\:p\mid x\ \ or\ \ p\mid y\:\Rightarrow\:up\mid x\ \ or\ \ up\mid y\:\Rightarrow\: up\:$ prime.

**Alternatively:** $\ $ Note $\rm\: (up) = (p)\:$ hence  $\rm\:D/(p) = D/(up),\ $ therefore

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} domain\ D/(p)&\iff&\rm \ domain\ D/(up)\\ \rm hence\ \ prime\,\ p&\iff&\rm\ prime\,\ up\end{eqnarray} $$

**Remark** $\ $ Irreducibilty follows similarly to the hint since

$$\rm irreducible\,\ q\, \iff\,  [\, q = xy\:\Rightarrow\: q\mid x\ \ or\ \ q\mid y\,]$$